# Cant get Google maps API key, getting errors in console

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I try to create a Google maps API key its says 'Couldn't create project'

Then I go to the console and click to create a project and get:

Error
com.google.apps.framework.request.StatusException:  generic::FAILED_PRECONDITION:

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new project in your Developer Console then enabled all the Google Maps API that you need to use. Now, go to Credentials -> Create redentials -> API key. Then, observe if you still experiencing this error. I'm not sure if this is a bug on the Google side, but you are not the only [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214920/failed-precondition-when-trying-to-create-a-new-google-api-project) who experience this issue